# iVars references strong, weak or what?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, instance-variables

In Obj-C, properties can be configured to be weak/strong. Instance variables. like following -

```
@interface MyClass {
NSObject *a;
}
```

Does the MyClass's object keep weak reference to `a` or strong, or something else? I think iVar is not released until its object is released.
Why don't we specify weak/strong for iVar like properties?

Answer (score 16):

the default reference to ivar is `__strong`, though you can explicitly set it to be `__weak` or `__strong`

---

Comment: Is there any way to declare the ivar as copy or assign?

Answer (score 15):

You question inspired me and i did a deep search on ObjectiveC memory management. I would like to share something with you that I got from Apple Doc.

**Default behavior of instance variable**

> Instance variable maintains a strong reference to the objects by default

**Why don't we specify weak/strong for iVar like properties?**

> Local variables and non-property instance variables maintain a strong references to objects by default. There’s no need to specify the strong attribute explicitly, because it is the default.
>   A variable maintains a strong reference to an object only as long as that variable is in scope, or until it is reassigned to another object or nil.
>
> If you don’t want a variable to maintain a strong reference, you can declare it as __weak, like this:

```
  NSObject * __weak weakVariable;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@interface MyClass {
__weak NSObject *a;
__strong NSObject *a;
__unsafe_unretained NSObject *obj;
}
```